# Warning: Undefined reference to function

Tags: c, function, undefined-reference

I keep getting the warning that my function has an undefined reference and that doesn't really say much to me or how to fix it. Here are the errors

> log_2.c: In function ‘main’: log_2.c:29: warning: implicit
>   declaration of function ‘logbase2’ /tmp/ccAXAmVb.o: In function
>   'main': log_2.c:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `logbase2'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Heres my code:

```
int logbasetwo (int number)
{
int test;
for (int i = 0; i< number; i++){
    test = 2 ^ i;
    int result = i;
}


return result;
}

int main(){

printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
int number = get_int();
int logresult;
if (number > 0){
logresult=logbase2(number);

}


else (number < 0){
    printf("Not a positive number. Re-enter: ");
    number = get_int(); 

}

printf("Log base two of number is:%i", logresult);


}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: change the line logresult=logbase2(number); to logresult=logbasetwo(number);

Comment: Note that `^` is XOR in c, **not** exponentation.

Comment: Instead of creating your `logbasetwo()` function, you could use `log2()` from `<math.h>`.

Answer (score 4):

Well, in your code , both `logbase2()` and `logbasetwo()` are used, which are not the same !!!

You have defined a function named `logbasetwo()`, but you called `logbase2()`.

Change either of them to match other one.

Also, you need to change the logic `test = 2 ^ i;`. As mentioned in earlier comment by Mr. **@Bathsheba**, `^` operator is for `XOR`, not exponentiation.

You need to use [`pow()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pow).